# Constructor in class cannot be applied to given types, when having a Superclass

Tags: java, bluej

Excuse me, I'm new to this.
I am currently using BlueJ and going through YouTube tutorials on Eclipse, but I need to use BlueJ for my assignment

I simply have to make a GUI called GadgetShop (which I have done), and it has buttons which add info from my Mobile and MP3 class. There is also a class called Gadget, which is the super-class.

So the issue I am having is with ArrayLists and gathering the info from the classes to display it in the Text Boxes I have made. I made an array list but I'm not sure what's wrong, because it says **constructor Gadget in class Gadget cannot be applied to given types;**

Here's the code needed in the GadgetShop:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GadgetShop implements ActionListener
{
private JTextField model, price, weight, size, credit, memory, phoneNo, duration, download, displayNumber;
private JButton addMobile, addMP3, clear, displayAll;

//These JTextField's are for the labels
private JTextField model2, price2, weight2, size2, credit2, memory2, phoneNo2, duration2, download2, displayNumber2;

private JFrame frame;
private ArrayList<Gadget> gadgetDetails;

public GadgetShop()
{
    makeFrame();
}

public static void main (String args[]){ 
    ArrayList<Gadget> GadgetList = new ArrayList<Gadget>();
    Gadget Object = new Gadget();
    GadgetList.add(Object.Gadget(model, price, weight, size));
}

public void addGadget(Gadget newGadget)
{
    gadgetDetails = new ArrayList<Gadget>();
    gadgetDetails.add(newGadget);        
    model.setText("s6");
```

My Gadget is this:

```
/**
*  Gadget that is a super class for the Mobile Phone and MP3.
*  Needs input for the price, weight, model and size.
*/
public class Gadget
{
// Variables
public double price;
public int weight;
public String model;
public String size;

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Gadget
 */
public Gadget(double ThePrice, int TheWeight, String TheModel, String TheSize)
{
    // initialise instance variables
    price = ThePrice;
    weight = TheWeight;
    model = TheModel;
    size = TheSize;
}

public double price()
{
   return price;
}

public int weight()
{
    return weight;
}

public String model()
{
    return model;
}

public String size()
{
    return size;
}

public void print()
{
   System.out.println("The price of the gadget is " + price + " pounds"); 
   System.out.println("The weight is " + weight + " grams");
   System.out.println("The model is " + weight); 
   System.out.println("The size is " + size);
}
}
```

What does it actually mean so I can fix this, and what's the recommended way to gather information from my classes to be entered into my text boxes when clicking the button? (I know how to activate button on clicks and add the information, but just don't know the best way to retrieve it)

Thank you for reading, I want to learn so this would help me extremely.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). 
- please [add](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) the *complete* error message.

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor for `Gadget` takes arguments:

```
public Gadget(double ThePrice, int TheWeight, String TheModel, String TheSize)
{
    // initialise instance variables
    price = ThePrice;
    weight = TheWeight;
    model = TheModel;
    size = TheSize;
}
```

You cannot simply call `new Gadget()` because the constructor needs four arguments. You have two options: firstly, you can provide the arguments in your main method:

```
public static void main (String args[]){ 
    ArrayList<Gadget> GadgetList = new ArrayList<Gadget>();
    Gadget object = new Gadget(1.00,20,"a model", "big");
    GadgetList.add(object);
}
```

Substitute whatever values make sense. The other solution is too create another constructor which doesn't take arguments in your `Gadget` class:

```
public Gadget() {
    //initialize values to default values
    price = 1.00
    weight = 21
    // etc.
}
```

You still have to fix the `main` method a little bit:

```
public static void main (String args[]){ 
    ArrayList<Gadget> GadgetList = new ArrayList<Gadget>();
    Gadget object = new Gadget();
    GadgetList.add(object);
}
```

Comment: But where you used: `Gadget object = new Gadget(1.00,20,"a model", "big");` I need it to not have default values as the GadgetShop needs to retrieve whatever is inputted. Is there a way for my GadgetShop to retrieved the information that is given?

Comment: @Dragon123 What's wrong with default values? They'll just get overwritten.

Comment: How do I actually get the information from the Mobile or MP3 to add text to the boxes in the GadgetShop?